# AWS S3 static bucket hosting-Internal Server Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-s3, static

I have set up an AWS S3 bucket to host a static website with my own URL. All permissions on the bucket and the files inside are public. I confirmed this by opening the public link for the index.html page. When I type in my URL (ianpritchard.com), I get an internal server error. I put logging on the bucket, and see an access denied on my request. Does anyone have any idea why? I did set up A records in my hosted zone.

```
<Error> 
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>xxx</RequestId>
  <HostId> xxxx </HostId>
</Error>
```

The bucket policy is here -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxx/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Post logs. Made public using bucket policy? ACL?

Comment: @Kashyap Thank you for your help. The log is here (the x characters are my obsfucation)-        <Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>xxx</RequestId>
<HostId>
xxxx
</HostId>
</Error>          The bucket policy is here - {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::xxxx/*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Accesd denied err, which S3 object/resource is it for?

Comment: It doesn't say in the log, but I think it would be for the index.html within the ianpritchard.com bucket. It is accessible via its public facing URL though.

Comment: @Kashyap One possible clue. When I look at the Registered Domain page in the AWS console, I see the nameservers from my original hosting company (ns1.netfirms.com and ns2.netfirms.com). In the DNS section, the NS record shows what looks like the correct Route 53 nameservers. Could that cause this issue? Is there something I can try to see if I can correct it? Rename the domain page nameservers?

Comment: Beyond this I can only say 1) to look at the logs of web server for more hints and 2) find concrete evidence of access to what is denied by s3. I still can't believe that it is index.html

Comment: Thank you. Since this is a static website hosted on S3, do I have access to webserver logs? The only log I could see was the S3 bucket log and that didn't tell me which resource was denied but I am sure I am missing something. I think I'll have to delete the bucket and hosted zone records and rebuild from the ground up and hope it works! No big deal, but it's very puzzling. Thanks for all your help and insights.

Comment: So there is something wrong in the way you've configured the S3 logs or you're talking abt some other logs altogether. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html the Request-URI clearly shows key/prefix/path and the method.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your setup is your IP is pointing to corporate IP instead of AWS.

There is a clean setup procedure given by AWS for hosting domains,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

in 4 steps.

Before You Begin

```
Step 1: Register a Domain
Step 2: Create and Configure Buckets and Upload Data
Step 3: Add Alias Records for example.com and www.example.com
Step 4: Testing
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Kannaiyan. I went through all of these steps-I have an A-record pointing to ianprtchard.com (the name of my site and my public bucket) pointing to the AWS bucket and an A-record for www.ianpritchard.com pointing to ianpritchard.com. The records look exactly like records fore a site I registered directly on Route 53 (rather than transferring the domain from a different registrar).

Answer (score 0):

You policy looks odd, resource should be `xxx/*` and principal should `*`:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"publicRead",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::xxxx/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

See some [example here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2)

Not sure why/how you're able to get `index.html`, post your public link for the index.html page:

Comment: Thank you @Kashyap. URL for index.html is https://s3.amazonaws.com/ianpritchard.com/index.html    When I cut and paste into StackOverflow it removes my asterisks but the policy does look how you suggest for principal and resource in AWS.